# Installing the Xperia Keyboard on non-Xperia devices

Tags: apk, sony-xperia, huawei

I recently went from a Sony Xperia phone to a Huawei P10 Lite.

I very much appreciated the Xperia keyboard I had, and would like to install it on this phone.

I thought that it would work on all Android devices. However, when I download the APK from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sony-mobile-communications/xperia-keyboard/) and try to install it, it says that it is not compatible with my phone.

I have tried to install an older version of the Xperia keyboard, but still without luck.

Does anybody know if it is possible to install the keyboard, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Post #456](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72947258&postcount=456)
 in the [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-sony-xperia-keyboard-phones-t3346736) provided by @beeshyams gives the following [download link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=4204965&d=1499483320) to the modified Xperia keyboard that can be used with a Huawei phone. 
When clicking on the download link, the download should start, and you simply install it as you would with any other apk package. However, always be careful when installing unauthorized packages. 
I don't know much about how this package is created and drawbacks, bugs, etc., but it works for me without any problems.

If you had a previous version of Xperia keyboard installed

> delete everything from the previous version! library, dalvik cache, just everything. Its really important.